# Comparar número dentro de um intervalo numérico

Tags: c#, .net, operadores

Quero criar uma função que receba um número e verifique se o mesmo está dentro de um intervalo de vai de 1 a 25. Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?

```
private int VerificaIntervalo(int numero)
{
    if (numero > 25)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `if(numero >= 1 && numero <= 25)` não serve?

Comment: @DiegoFelipe,sua resposta está certa!

Comment: @itasouza Acha que pode aceitar alguma das respostas?

Answer (score 5):

É bem mais simples que outras opções:

```
private bool VerificaIntervalo(int numero) => numero >= 1 && numero <= 25;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/RangeValidation.cs).

Idealmente o nome do método poderia ser mais explicativo do que se refere isto.

Comment: Pois é, eu tentei! +1

Comment: Prolixidade é um grande mal.

Comment: @jbueno em código sem úvida. Em textos didáticos, não :) O que muita gente não entende é que prolixidade quando está ensinando é uma ferramenta.

Answer (score 2):

o mais simples seria:

```
private bool VerificaIntervalo(int numero)
{
   if(numero >= 1 && numero <= 25)
     return true;
   else
     return false;
}
```

Comment: Ao invéz do `if` ´pode utilizar apenas `return numero >= 1 && numero <= 25;`.

Comment: sim, também seria uma boa opção

Answer (score 1):

Aqui um exemplo para você verificar se os números estão no intervalo entre 1 a 25, veja abaixo:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        if (comparaNumero(90))
           Console.WriteLine("Dentro do intervalo entre 1 a 25");
        else
           Console.WriteLine("Fora do intervalo");
    }

    public static bool comparaNumero(int n)
    {
        return (n >= 1 && n <= 25);
    }
}
```

Veja funcionado no [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/dDYbiC).

Answer (score 0):

```
private bool VerificaIntervalo(int numero)
    {
          if(numero >= 1 && numero <= 25)
          {
            return true;
          }
          else
          {
           return false;
          }
    }
```

Seria isso?

Comment: Agradeço a todas as respostas